# How to show more Labels from the Parameter Dataset?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I using the following Parameter Dataset.

[Parameter Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZ8nn.png)

I use the value, and the reader just see the label. But is it possible additional to use a **second label**?

For example: Reader select Mike, and additional I see a second label (Mikky) in the Report?

I tried

`=Parameters!Names.Label2`

But SSRS does not show the Name "Mikky".

Comment: You can only have one label per parameter. You can try to combine your labels into one label in the dataset. Like "Mike (Mikky)"

Comment: It does not work. We need solutions

Comment: As papermoon88 stated, Parameters are just key/value pairs so you can only have 1 value and one associated label. Assuming your parameter is populated from a dataset, just include that in your report either by editing your dataset query that give you the data displayed in the report or doing a `LOOKUP()` to get the additional column.

Comment: The only way to retrieve any extra fields like the nickname, is having a second dataset and passing the Id as an argument to retrieve them from the database. Then you can use the field values inside your report.

Answer (score 0):

Why not UNION your table for the Name's parameter query?

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TABLE
UNION
SELECT ID, NICKNAME
FROM TABLE
WHERE NICKNAME IS NOT NULL
```

This would give you two records for each ID that has a nickname. Selecting either Mike or Mikky would get you an ID of 1.

Comment: Do not get it. Where is the solution?